# Impossible Viewpoint using Azimuth and Elevation

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I can't seem to achieve the following 3D plot view orientation using the `view([AZ,EL])` command.
[image: Impossible coordinate system orientation?]

No matter how hard I try rotating my 3D plot in the figure using the mouse or the command `view` itself, I just can't get that viewing angle. Is there another way of specifying the viewpoint?

Comment: By `axes` you mean the original axes, or some 'fake' ones? The following doesn't produce what I need: `peaks; view(gca,[60 45]); xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z')`

Comment: Take a look at [`campos`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/campos.html)

Comment: I tried playing with `campos`, `camtarget`, and `camup` and almost got there, but not quite. Being a regular 3D CAD user I was hoping that there would be a way of rotating the scene in the Figure GUI arbitrarily, but none of the options in the _Camera Toolbar_ seems to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve these sorts of views using [camera control functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/views.html), in this case [`camorbit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/camorbit.html) and [`camroll`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/camroll.html):

```
[X, Y, Z] = peaks();
hAxes = gca;
surf(hAxes, X, Y, Z);
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
zlabel('z');
camorbit(-90, 0);
camroll(hAxes, -111);
```

[image]

Notice that positive x is pointing up and to the right, positive z is pointing down and to the right, and positive y is pointing up.

I've done a lot of 3D visualization in MATLAB, and have put together some tools I routinely use for manipulating the view with the mouse. I posted one such tool on the [MathWorks File Exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) called [`MouseManager`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/61975-mousemanager). [One of the demos](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/61975/versions/2/previews/html/MouseManager_demo.html?access_key=#12) I included in the submission is an example for how to create mouse-based manipulation of the view (rotating, dollying, and zooming).

Comment: That tool is ❤.

Comment: @SardarUsama: Glad you like it. It's become the workhorse of pretty much all of my GUIs. ;)

Comment: What can I say, the MouseManager is just spot on.