# How to get the handle of curves plotted by contour3 in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, rotation, contour, handle

When I want to rotate the lines ploted using `contour3`, it seems like the graphic handles of the lines are already deleted. How can I get the handle of the contour lines? Or is it possible to rotate the lines with the contour matrix `C`?

```
>> x = -2:0.25:2; x = -2:0.25:2;
>> [X,Y] = meshgrid(x);
>> Z = X.*exp(-X.^2-Y.^2);
>> C=contour3(X,Y,Z,10,'m');
>> hd=gca;
>> rotate(hd,[0 1 0],90,[0 0 0]);
```

The lines did't move after entering the last command. (I'm using MATLAB 2016a.)
[image]

Comment: why do you have `h` in `rotate`? Shouldn't it be `C`?

Comment: or `hd`, basically `h` does not exist in this code

Comment: I'm sorry, I just made a mistake, I meant to rotate hd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the second output from [`contour3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour3.html), which is the handle to the [`Contour` graphics object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour-properties.html):

```
[C, h] = contour3(...);
```

Unfortunately, this won't help you with your rotation problem. From the documentation for [`rotate`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rotate.html):

> `rotate(h,direction,alpha)` rotates the graphics object `h` by `alpha` degrees. Specify `h` as a surface, patch, line, text, or image object. ...

Note that `rotate` won't work on [`axes`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html) or `Contour` objects. Instead, you'll need to alter the camera view with [`view`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Actually, I wanted to make the z axis direction looks inclined, which seems hard for me to achieve with `view`. Is there any other function to do this?

Comment: @WANGGuosheng: For that, you'll need to use other camera control tools, as I mention in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43479327/52738).